# How to save my 1-meter-high Aloe Vera plant which broke off at the stem?

Tags: plant-care, succulents, aloe

My aloe plant broke at the stem, all leaves and about 1 inch of stem remain.

Can I re-plant the broken section and will it grow again from the broken stem?

Answer (score 5):

I have many times planted a broken off piece of aloe vera and had it root and grow on into a new plant.  Find some sandy soil, water it well but let it drain completely, stick the stem of the broken off part into the soil and give it a couple or three weeks.  Keep it in bright but not direct light, and water it *sparingly*.  You can be pretty sure it has rooted when you try to gently tug it out of the soil but it resists, and almost certain of rooting when it begins to put on new growth.