# How to fix an aloe plant broken off from its root?

Tags: roots, aloe, repotting

My aloe plant broke off from its root in the pot.  It looked healthy and I have it sitting in water at the moment.

Will it get a new root started in the water, or it is best to try repotting?

Comment: Also: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/9212/how-to-save-my-1-meter-high-aloe-vera-plant-which-broke-off-at-the-stem